# Are Brazilian "Adult Only" hotels suitable for regular stays?

Tags: hotels, brazil

Looking for hotels in Brazil turns up several (cheap) options with "Adult Only" in their description. E.g. [Hotel Gomes Freire (Adult Only)](https://www.booking.com/hotel/br/gomes-freire.html) or [Shelton Hotel (Adult Only)](https://www.booking.com/hotel/br/shelton-rio-de-janeiro.html). The description for the first one says:

> Only 2.4 miles from the Santos Dumont Airport, Hotel Gomes Freire is an adults-only love hotel that features a hot tub and room service.

Are these kinds of hotels acceptable for regular tourists, who just need a place to sleep?

Comment: @pnuts noise is probably fine. Having escorts knock on your door for a late night sales bonanza is probably not :)

Comment: I used to stay in hotels of this kind in Mexico City about twenty years ago before backpacker hostels were a thing there. At least in that country/city there were never escorts knocking on doors. Everything was clean but varying degrees of worn out. Sometimes there would be mirrored ceilings and there would always be 24-hour porn channels on the TV. Most also had discrete parking. Otherwise they were just like most other cheap run down hotels. Lots of budget travellers used to stay in them. In China however, I have had escorts barge into my room while I was trying to check in! (-:

Comment: @hippietrail Discrete parking or discreet parking?

Comment: @Coxy: Dammit! I even Googled the difference to help pick the right spelling first - and still got it wrong! d-:

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't stayed in either of those hotels. However I slept in love hotels, so the answer to your question "Are these kinds of hotels acceptable for regular tourists, who just need a place to sleep", is Yes.

There are a few things, however, to keep in mind:

1. With love hotels, you are much more likely to get a windowless room. If this is a concern, call the hotel. Do not assume that the booking site will list your room as "windowless"; sometime they do not. Myself I actually prefer those rooms as they tend to be much quieter, especially next to airport where most sound comes through the windows.
2. Typical love hotel visitors do not come there to have an overnight sleep. Thus you might hear certain noise. Good hotels however do separate sleeping guest from the hourly guests (usually by floor or put them in a different section). Make sure you tell the hotel at checking that you're staying overnight and want to have a good sleep. Still bringing earplugs is not a bad idea.
3. Some love hotels, notably in Japan, offer "rest" rates (overnight sleep) which is typically 10pm-8am. **Once you get in, you have to stay until the morning - as soon as you leave, your stay ends.** So if you leave, for example, to have a late dinner, your stay is finished. However hotels advertised at booking.com type websites typically do NOT do that and act more like a normal hotel; this is more of a concern if you just walk in.
4. Some love hotels might not check in a single guest, two people of the same sex, or more than two people. So if you're traveling not as a (different sex) couple, you might check it with a hotel.
5. Some love hotels only accept cash, even if they have the "Visa" sign. A typical excuse is "credit card machine not working". So if you want to pay with a credit card, book on a site like Agoda or orbitz, which allow you to prepay for your stay.
6. Don't expect other hotel amenities like laundry or luggage storage.
7. Mattresses there tend to be plastic-wrapped (for obvious reasons), so it feels a bit differently.

Also keep in mind that in those hotels you might get a better price by walking in, instead of booking in advance (booking sites charge at least 10% "service fee"). In some countries even the posted price could be negotiable. Just call/email the hotel **before booking on the booking site** and ask if they can give you a better price. Expect to pay cash in this case.

Regarding issues, I have never had any in those hotels; the rooms were same or cleaner comparing to "regular" hotels in a similar price range, and the soundproofing was better. There was never soliciting of any kind, and nobody knocks on your door/rings a phone.

Comment: When you say "love hotels" are you referring specifically to Japanese love hotels? I think many people understand them to be a Japanese thing. Or are you referring to a broader category?

Comment: No, I refer to a broader category. Love hotels exists in many countries; I stayed in those in Japan, Singapore, Philippines and Taiwan. However there are things specific only to Japan - at least from my experience - such as no in-and-out privileges.

Comment: I thought the whole point was "in-and-out privileges"...

Comment: Those kind of "love hotel" is very common and in Brazil they are called "Motel". As the asnwer explains they purpose is to provide a nice place to a couple have a few hours of fun time. They often have a "pernoite" (stay at night) option but they usually have check in, check out time likely 10:00 pm to 10:00 am. Best contact the "Motel" ahead to check the price for the time you plan to stay.